# Errors using get-random to set argb

Tags: powershell

I am trying to give the .BackColor of a panel a random color.

```
$rndm1 = Get-Random -minimum 50 -maximum 240
$rndm2 = Get-Random -minimum 50 -maximum 240
$rndm3 = Get-Random -minimum 50 -maximum 240
```

This obviously works:

```
$pBar.BackColor = [System.Drawing.color]::FromArgb(60,60,60)
```

But using the random numbers don't:

```
$rndmResult = ("'" + $rndm1 + ',' + $rndm2 + ',' + $rndm3 + "'")
$pBar.BackColor = [System.Drawing.color]::FromArgb($rndmResult)
```

I've written that code in so many different ways, but none seem to work. I've also tried to write the $`rndm` variables in ways like this `$rndm1 = ("'" + (Get-Random -minimum 50 -maximum 240) + "'")` - but I can't get around it. What am I doing wrong? The error output is:

`ERROR: Cannot convert argument "argb", with value: "'117,56,167'", for "FromArgb" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "'117,56,167'" to type "System.Int32".`

or

`ERROR: Cannot convert value "," to type "System.Int32". Error: "The input string had invalid format."`

depending on how I place the `"` and `'`.

*Powershell studio 2016*

Comment: `[System.Drawing.color]::FromArgb($rndm1,$rndm2,$rndm3)` works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you are passing 3 distinct integers:

```
$pBar.BackColor = [System.Drawing.color]::FromArgb(60,60,60)
```

Here, you are passing a string:

```
$rndmResult = ("'" + $rndm1 + ',' + $rndm2 + ',' + $rndm3 + "'")
$pBar.BackColor = [System.Drawing.color]::FromArgb($rndmResult)
```

Instead, pass the integers directly:

```
$pBar.BackColor = [System.Drawing.color]::FromArgb($rndm1,$rndm2,$rndm3)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. Thats probably the only thing I didn't try... :) Again - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this step:

```
$rndmResult = ("'" + $rndm1 + ',' + $rndm2 + ',' + $rndm3 + "'")
```

you create the string `'156,93,194'` (assuming Get-Random generated the numbers 156, 93 and 194).

`FromArgb()` has no overloads that take a single string as it's argument.

Pass the values directly to the functino instead:

```
[System.Drawing.color]::FromArgb($rndm1,$rndm2,$rndm3)
```

Comment: Didn't know I the FromArgb() couldn't take a string as it's argument, guess that's where I was failing big time. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MadsTheMan For future reference, you can either enter the method name without brackets (like this `[System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb`) and hit enter in the prompt or look up [the documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to see valid overloads for a method

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely use that from now on. :)